# Elasticsearch 5.5.0 maven dependency issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to work with `elasticsearch` version `5.5.0` in java. so this i added maven dependency to `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

when run the project throws this exception.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Field$TermVector

for this problem added this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

after this exception throws.

> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LATEST

How fix this problem. 
Thanks

**Edit**

[image: maven dependency tree]

Answer (score 0):

ES 5.5.0 uses Lucene 6.6.0 so you should try with this dependency instead

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
  <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this exception throws. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.document.Field$TermVector`

Comment: Can you run this and update your question with the output: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` ?

Comment: I put dependency tree of  my project. I use `Intellij IDEA`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. but second exception throws.